# how to get theme attributes (name and id) are used in for every single activity in android

Tags: android-manifest, android-theme, android-styles

I want to get current theme id and name for every single activity.
I have used this code

```
int theme = 0;
        String themeName = null;

        try {
            String packageName = context.getPackageName();
            PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            theme = packageInfo.applicationInfo.theme;
            themeName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(theme);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Manifest File code

```
<application
        android:name="com.ext.MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppSoundOnTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.ext.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

    <activity
            android:name="com.ext.HomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
 </application>
```

styles.xml code

```
<style name="AppSoundOffTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:soundEffectsEnabled">false</item>
    </style>

     <style name="AppSoundOnTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:soundEffectsEnabled">true</item>
    </style>
```

and it returns same theme id and name for all activities.
I think it gives application class's theme attributes.
How can i find different theme attributes for all activities separately.

Comment: post your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: define theme in each activity separately and then access theme id

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick way I found:

```
String packageName = getPackageName();
        PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES|PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);          //Changed flags to fetch activies as well
        ActivityInfo[] activities = packageInfo.activities;                                                                                             //retrieve activities in the app
        for (ActivityInfo activityInfo : activities) {
            try {                                                                                                                                       //Traverse for every activity
                Log.d("theme", "Checking for " + activityInfo.name);
                int theme = activityInfo.getThemeResource();                                                                                            //retrieve 'int' resource ID
                String themeName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(theme);
                Log.d("theme", themeName);                                                                                                              //Retrieve theme name
            } catch (Exception e) {     
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

It pretty much uses the block of code you've used, with a little tweak. Seemed to work for me, let me know  if you still have trouble.

PS: You may want to put this block in a `try-catch` block.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is working fine when theme is set into manifest file but when removed from manifest and set at runtime on activity it returns theme id is 0.In this case how to detect theme id.

Comment: That would depend on where you're placing the call for this check. It should be done after you set the theme at run time.

Comment: @SlashG I am calling `setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog);` before `setContentView` method and trying your code in `onResume` method. But still I am getting `AppTheme` instead of `Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog`

Comment: @HarishGyanani It is possible that this code doesn't work for themes set using `setTheme()`, since OP too didn't get results. Let me try out another method.

Comment: @HarishGyanani, do you wish to get your current theme only?

Comment: @SlashG not just current activity, for all activities. can it be done in base activity or in application class?

Comment: @HarishGyanani, if you wish to get data for all activities, even ones that haven't been created, you can't get the correct theme data. Since the code where you set the theme hasn't been called for those.

Comment: @SlashG for those activities, which are available in back stack.